# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic) => Null))

Tags: flutter

i got this problem while trying to fetch data from api

> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic) => Null))

im not sure if its the api link is wrong or you need a proper way to get those datas, my code:

```
getTrendingWallpapers() async {
var response = await http.get(
Uri.parse("https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?page=2&per_page=40"),
    headers: {"Authorizations": apiKey});

Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
jsonData["photos"].forEach((element) {
  print(element);
  
});

setState(() {});
}
```

this is my wallpaper_model.dart
i did put some late and required on those variables, im not sure whether they affects them or not

```
class WallpaperModel {
  late String photographer;
  late String photographer_url;
  late int photographer_id;
  late SrcModel src;
WallpaperModel(
 {
    required this.src,
    required this.photographer_url,
    required this.photographer_id,
    required this.photographer});

factory WallpaperModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
  return WallpaperModel(
  src: SrcModel.fromMap(jsonData["src"]),
  photographer_url: jsonData["photographer_url"],
  photographer_id: jsonData["photographer_id"],
  photographer: jsonData["photographer"]);
  }
}
```

how do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the Response body of the API call. Check whether the body is null or is your even request going through properly. Postman is good in such scenarios as it allows you to get an idea of whether the request works and how the response body is structured.

Comment: i tried adding the query into the api like this 
https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=coding&per_page=15&page=1
and it worked. 
https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?page=2&per_page=40 doesnt work because it didnt have the 'query' i believe?

Comment: I believe you need to confirm the proper usage of their API's through their documentation. Check what params are required, optional and if they are GET or POST or some other type of call.